# Is there a single command to run tests from both clojure.test and Speclj?

Tags: testing, clojure, functional-programming, leiningen, speclj

I have an already working application that has some tests written with clojure.test

I want to create some new tests to raise code coverage, but this time using Speclj since tests look nicer.

However, now in order to make sure all tests are passing, I need to run lein test to run tests from clojure.test and lein spec to run tests from speclj.

Is there a single command to run all the tests no matter the library I chose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify an alias in leiningen, add the following line to  project.clj:

```
:aliases {"test-all" ["do" ["test"] ["spec"]]}
```

and run it with `lein test-all`

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. I was starting to think the only way would be creating a leiningen plugin for it, but your suggestion was way better.